# How to display selected columns of database in a Jtable?

Tags: java, sql, jtable

I successfully populated my `JTable` with the contents of my database table but I only want to show selected columns of it. Is there any way of doing this? Or is it even possible to select which column to display in a `JTable`?

Here is the method of populating my `JTable`

```
    private void Update_table() {
        try {
            String sql = "select * from Members";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            Members_Table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

My database table name is "Members". "Members_Table" is the name of my `JTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try changing your sql statement to only select the columns you are interested in. For instance, if Members has the columns "MemberId", "MemberFirstName", "MemberLastName" "MemberAddressFK", and you only wanted to display MemberFirstName and MemberLastName, you could change your sql to be

```
String sql = "select MemberFirstName, MemberLastName from Members";
```

You can find more details about the sql select statement at http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-select-statement.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a bit more robust data model on the Java side and want to hide the columns in the JTable, you can use [removeColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) from JTable. This *does not remove* the column from the Table model, only from visible presentation. If you keep track of which columns are hidden or visible, you can easily put the column back in, and its data will still be properly associated.

For example, to remove the first column, you could use:

```
myTable.removeColumn(myTable.getColumnModel().get(0)); 
// i don't remember if it's 0-index or 1-index for first column
```

As an example, I would dynamically fill a JPanel with checkboxes for each column and then checking and unchecking individual boxes would hide and disable those columns. This allows you to keep all the data, but only present those relevant to the user at the time, similar to how hiding columns in Excel works.